# JavaFX Project not showing

Tags: java, javafx

Below I have the code to launch my JavaFX GUI for a project I am working on. However when I go to execute the classes, it gets stuck. All it prints is Starting MCPY GUI and just sits there any help?

Launcher class

```java
public class MCPY {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Starting MCPY GUI...");   
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

Main

```java
package com.mcpy.gui;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("styles/Main.fxml"));
        Parent root;

        try {
            root = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // log exception
            return;
        }

        //init the connection to the controller class
        MainController MainController = loader.getController();
        MainController.setMain(this);

       //load the scene
       primaryStage.setTitle("Minecraft Launcher Python");
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));
       primaryStage.show();

    };


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Main.FXML

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<TitledPane animated="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="Minecraft Launcher Python Login Screen" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mcpy.gui.MainController">
    <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="135.0" fitWidth="119.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                    <image>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <Button id="play" layoutX="231.0" layoutY="176.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#playButtonActionEvent" text="Play" />
                <Button id="login" layoutX="313.0" layoutY="176.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginButtonEvent" text="Login" />
                <Button id="create_account" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="176.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#create_accountButtonEvent" text="Create Account" />
            </children></AnchorPane>
    </content>
</TitledPane>
```

MainController

```java
package com.mcpy.gui;


import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import com.mcpy.gui.Play;
import com.mcpy.gui.Login;
import com.mcpy.gui.CreateAccount;
/* Logic for the main gui. DO NOT EDIT. */
public class MainController {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Main main;

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;

    }
    @FXML
    private static Button login;

    @FXML
    private static Button create_account;

    @FXML 
    private static Button play;

    @FXML
    public void loginButtonEvent(ActionEvent lbe) {
        String[] args = (null);        
        Login.main(args);
    };

    @FXML    
    public void create_accountButtonEvent(ActionEvent cabe) {
        String[] args = (null);          
        CreateAccount.main(args);
    };

    @FXML    
    public void playButtonActionEvent(ActionEvent pbae) {       
        Play.play_mc();
    }
}
```

All of the code is here. The Launcher (MCPY.java) the main gui and its respecitve controller and the stylesheet (Main.java, MainController.java and Main.FXML)

EDIT: I have applied the FXML changes suggested by @naimdjon, however upon clicking the button this error is produced: https://pastebin.com/8EV9wfnm

Comment: How do `Main.fxml` and  `MainController` look like?

Comment: Without any information regarding the folder structure and the project setup, it seems like  you are getting exception on line ` root = loader.load();`

Comment: @naimdjon I don't believe so. Let me see what the console has to say.

Comment: The fxml file is not a valid xml, is it missing the root <TitledPane> tag or is it a typo?

Comment: @naimdjon The root element was there, the OP simply formatted the markdown incorrectly.

Comment: Deleting your `Main.main` will solve your new error. `Application` can start itself, just not need `main`.

Comment: do not use static scope! it's nearly always _not_ what you want, and plain wrong for fields that should be injected (they aren't)

Comment: Thanks for the help. So @DQYuan how would you implement deleting Main.main(), wouldn't there have to be a call somewhere for the application to start?

Comment: a) one problem per question b) for each provide a [mcve] demonstrating that problem (_not_ your whole code, but a stripped down example written exclusively for the task to demonstrate what's wrong) c) stick java naming conventions, please!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple namespace declaration in your xml and imports were missing. Change your fxml to this (removed image for testing), this shows a window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<TitledPane fx:controller="com.mcpy.gui.MainController" animated="false"
            maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
            minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
            text="Minecraft Launcher Python Login Screen"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="135.0" fitWidth="119.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                    <image>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <Button id="play" layoutX="231.0" layoutY="176.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Play" />
                <Button id="login" layoutX="313.0" layoutY="176.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login" />
                <Button id="create_account" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="176.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create Account" />
            </children></AnchorPane>
    </content>
</TitledPane>
```

**UPDATE**

Upon clicking on the button, you seem to be calling the `launch()` method. You can't call launch() method more than once in a Java FX application.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! You solved my original issue. However there is a new error that is thrown every time I click create account or login. A link to the error can be found in the edit.

Comment: @ConnorTozer time for reading and understand a basic tutorial on javafx in general and fxml in particular - without the basics you can't make much progress in your project/s :)